# Test work properly on Chrome, not on Firefox

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I wrote test using TestNG and selenium.

```
code...
actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
        actions.build().perform();
code...
```

I wanted to delete text in login window using these sendKeys, with DataProvider

```
@DataProvider(name = "inputs")
public Object[][] getData() {
    return new Object[][]{
            {"000000000", true},
            {"000000000", true}
    };
}
```

Html:

```
<div><input type="tel" class="valid TextInput-kJdagG iVdKHC" name="recoveryPhone" id="eb69ff0b-3427-6986-7556-b7af40ffb156" aria-describedby="eb69ff0b-3427-6986-7556-b7af40ffb156" value="+48 "></div>
```

Error message:

```
Unable to read VR 
Path1523545392670   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
1523545393744   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 52644
1523545394180   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
```

Test work as I expected on Chrome, but on firefox these sendKeys not always mark the text, and clear this text. In project I have to use action class. Why the test runs differently?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Check this post https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/665 against your versions (browser, browser driver, selenium etc which are always sensible to include in any question), it could be a known bug with the geckodriver.

The post includes a work around of creating the chord in a different way, using:

```
List<CharSequence> keyWithModifiers = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
keyWithModifiers.add(Keys.CONTROL);
keyWithModifiers.add("a");
String ctrlA = Keys.chord(keyWithModifiers);
textFieldElem.sendKeys(ctrlA);
```

This approach worked for me using Selenium 3.7.1 Java bindings, gecko driver 0.18.0 (64 bit) and Firefox 57.0.2 - 59.0